# Filter a list on multiple columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I need to filter my list based on multiple columns. here is my class that I need to search

```
public class psdata
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Customer { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public string Zip { get; set; }
        public decimal? Identification { get; set; }
        public decimal? Assesment { get; set; }
        public decimal? PayoffLedger { get; set; }
        public decimal? RentRestrictions { get; set; }
        public decimal? CCR { get; set; }
        public decimal SubTotal { get; set; }
    }
```

And here is my linq query that looks at my list and then will find the search term if it is contained in the column.

```
var sl = list.Where<psdata>( c => c.Address.ToLower().Contains(text));
```

This works great for the first column. However if I want to add another column as so.

```
var sl = list.Where<psdata>( c => c.Address.ToLower().Contains(text) || c => c.City.ToLower().Contains(text));
```

I get an error

```
Operator || cannot be applied to operands of the type bool and psdata.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're passing more than one lambda expression to `where` rather than using `&&` or `||` in your lambda expression to combine multiple comparisons.

this;
`c => c.Address.ToLower().Contains(text) || c => c.City.ToLower().Contains(text)`

should be;  `c => c.Address.ToLower().Contains(text) || c.City.ToLower().Contains(text)`

Answer (score 9):

Your only issue is the second `c =>`. You're still only passing a single Lambda expression, it just needs to include the `||` operator:

```
var sl = list.Where(c => c.Address.ToLower().Contains(text) ||
    c.City.ToLower().Contains(text));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var sl = list.Where<psdata>( c => c.Address.ToLower().Contains(text) || c => c.City.ToLower().Contains(text));
```

should be

```
var sl = list.Where<psdata>( c => c.Address.ToLower().Contains(text) || c.City.ToLower().Contains(text));
```

You don't need the second 'goes to' `=>` operator in your expression.

Answer (score 2):

If you review the signature of [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534803(v=vs.100).aspx) clause, it's expecting a `Func<TSource, Boolean>`. Meaning you have to pass in a function that takes a type TSource, and returns boolean. We are passing an anonymous function as the argument. The syntax for anonymous function is, `(argument)=>{ expression }`. So, your code can be interpreted as

```
list.Where<psdata>(Func<psdata,bool>||Func<psdata,bool>)
```

which would obviously not behave as expected. So the solution would be

```
list.Where<psdata>(c => c.Address.ToLower().Contains(text) 
|| c.City.ToLower().Contains(text));
```